# Newtons Method and the smallest interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

The exercise in my book asks me to find the smallest positive starting point for which Newton's method diverges when it is applied to $f(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$.

I know that newtons method converges if $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1} = r$, where $r$ is the root of $f(x)$ and $x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$. So this means if $|x_{n+1}| < |x_n|$ for all iterations then $x_{n+1} \to r$.

If that absolute value inequality is true, then newton's method diverges when $|x_{n+1}| \geq |x_{n}|$. For this to happen, then there is a pair of points $x_{n+1}$ and $x_{n}$ s.t. $x_{n+1} = -x_{n}$. After that occurs, we have $|x_{n+1}| > |x_{n}|$. Since the equality happens first, then that means the smallest interval of convergence is the interval with endpoints which are when $x_{n+1} = -x_{n}$ is true. Ironically, I can find this point with Newton's Method, but I need someone to verify my logic.

Is my reasoning correct? Is there anything wrong with what I said?

Comment: Let $N(x) = x-f(x)/f'(x)$ and show that $N(N(x)) = x$ has a unique, positive solution. Of course, you'll need to find it numerically.

Comment: @MarkMcClure $N(N(x)) =x$ I think means what I said in my post. That $x_{n+1} = -x_n$, an oscillation point. But that isn't what my post here is about since i'm more confused on the logic of what is going on.

Comment: Suppose that $N(N(x))-x=0$ has a unique, positive solution, say $x^*$. Thus, $N(N(x))=x$ has exactly three solutions at $-x^*$, zero, and $x^*$ and between those solutions $N(N(x))-x$ does not change sign. Thus, $N(N(x))<x$ for $x\in(0,x^*)$ and $N(N(x))>x$ for $x>x^*$. As a result, the orbit of any initial seed in $(-x^*,x^*)$ will converge to zero under iteration of $N$, while the orbit of any initial seed outside of that interval will diverge. The claim that $N(N(x))-x=0$ has a unique, positive solution still remains to be shown, but you've got plenty of tools from calculus to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g(x)=x-\arctan(x)(1+x^2)$. Notice that $g$ is odd. Show that for large enough negative $x$, $g(x)>-x$, and for large enough positive $x$, $g(x)<-x$. By the oddness of $g$, these are equivalent. Call the positive cutoff $x^*$ (so the negative cutoff is $-x^*$). (Hint: the "driving force" behind this behavior is the $x^2$ term becoming large; this can be used to show this result without explicitly calculating $x^*$).

Finally, if $|x_{n+1}|>|x_n|>x^*$ then $|x_{n+2}|>|x_{n+1}|$, and so by induction you get the divergent behavior.

Note that this proof so far gives you no guarantees of convergence inside $(-x^*,x^*)$.

Comment: I don't see why $g(x) < -x$ would be true for large enough positive $x$. Could you explain why?

Comment: @Taln For large enough positive $x$, $x^2>x$ and $\arctan(x)>1$.

Comment: Ian, and why exactly do we care about $g(x) < -x$? To be clear, $g(x)$ represents the points in Newton's Method right? So what does it mean if $g(x) < -x$ for some $x$? I'm just having trouble understanding what we are doing

Comment: @Taln The point is to understand the behavior of the iteration for $|x|>x^*$, which is alternating in sign and progressively growing in absolute value. Technically, what I said here does not actually show that $|x_n| \to \infty$ in this case, but it does show that the $|x_n|$ will never dip below $x^*$ and that $x_n$ will continue to alternate in sign, which is enough.

Comment: @Taln  It is a good idea to visualize this by drawing the graph: once $x$ is large, the Newton iteration will send you to an even bigger negative $x$, since $\arctan'(x) \to 0^+$ as $x \to \infty$. Then the same thing happens on the other side, *ad infinitum*.

Comment: Ian, I understand it now. Drawing the picture was essential. Thanks!